# Event Handler in Java between two classes

Tags: java

I am interested to get ActionEvent generated by multiple components from another class... please help. Example is given below.

```
class MyFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        Container c = window.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Save");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Delete");
        c.add(btn1);
        c.add(btn2);
        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
        btn1.addActionListener(handler);
        btn2.addActionListener(handler);
        .................
    }
}
class EventHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        // what can i do here to get Event and also recognized which component fired event?
        // I have used getSource(). but problem is not solved.
        if ( ae.getSource() == btnSave)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

please help me as soon as possible...

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Why can't you just use two handlers?

Answer (score 1):

In general if you have multiple JButton you can set the action command for each component

```
...
btn1.addActionListener(handler);
btn1.setActionCommand("save");
btn2.addActionListener(handler);
btn2.setActionCommand("delete");
...
```

in the handler you can get the action command

```
class EventHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        String actionCommand = ((JButton) ae.getSource()).getActionCommand();

        if (actionCommand.equals("save")) {
                ...
        }else if (actionCommand.equals("delete") {
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
JButton temp = (JButton) ae.getSource();
if(temp.getText().equals("Save")) {
    ...
}
```

Another way would be to pass buttons references using EventHandler parameterized constructor, and after that add it as listener:

```
EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(btn1, btn2);
btn1.addActionListener(handler);
btn2.addActionListener(handler);
```

And then modify EventHandler class:

```
class EventHandler implements ActionListener {
    JButton b1, b2;

    public EventHandler(JButton b1, JButton b2) {
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        JButton temp = (JButton) ae.getSource();

        if(temp == b1)
        {
             ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read on `ActionEvent` [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/do-2001-1/jdk1.3/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) to find out how to handle it.

> get ActionEvent generated by multiple components from another class

do you want a event handler to know from which it came?

for that you can do

```
JButton temp = (JButton) ae.getSource();
```

as was suggested and then get the button text with

```
temp.getText();
```

and compare it to the button's text if you don't have the button's instance. if you have just compare the two